# Object variable or with block variable not set error message when trying to create a range

Tags: vba

So I've got the following piece of code

```
Dim range_to_sum As Range
range_to_sum = "D" & paste_failures_row & ":" & "D" & lrow_4
```

and if I delete the "Dim range_to_sum as range" line I get D22:D43 which is exactly what I want, but once I add that line I get a "object variable or with block variable not set" why is this? I need this to be a range so that then I can use it for a sum function later on my code.

Comment: `Set range_to_sum = ActiveSheet.Range("D" & paste_failures_row & ":" & "D" & lrow_4)`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you very much. This worked, if you post it as an answer I can select it as an answer to my problem.